# When Microsoft releases Windows 10 updates? Is there some public list available?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I would like to know **when Microsoft releases Windows 10 updates - is there some public list available**?

The reason is that I would like to compare these days to days when there is slow Internet connection in our company to see if it correlates... And if it does, take some steps to make it better. Thank you.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have any lingering questions?

Comment: I think the combination of your answer and @fleet-command's responds to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.  For future reference, please keep mind that within your resolved questions you can flag one of the proposed answers as `Accepted`.  It appears that you have never actually done that before, so here is a short tutorial from the Help Center:  [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: well, the problem is that both answers answer the problem, so It is not correct to mark just one - and that happens often :/

Answer (score 2):

If your emphasis on on the operating system itself, Microsoft maintains an official page that shows the specific availability date, version, and build number of their updates:

[Windows 10 Release History](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-info.aspx)

Please keep in mind that for major version updates (like the Anniversary Update, version 1607), the Windows Update release is staggered.  However, the build updates (currently 14393.693) are released simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft releases updates on [Patch Tuesdays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_Tuesday). According to Wikipedia:

> Patch Tuesday occurs on the second, and sometimes fourth, Tuesday of each month in North America. As far as the integrated Windows Update (WU) function is concerned, Patch Tuesday begins at 18:00 or 17:00 UTC (10:00 PST (UTC−8) or 10:00 PDT (UTC−7). The updates show up in Download Center before they are added to WU, and the KB articles and the Technet bulletin are unlocked later.

For the purpose you explained, you can look up [Microsoft Security Bulletins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletins). There, you can even subscribe to alerts for updates.